# Run python script when computer is not being used?

Tags: python, bash, macos

I recently got into machine-learning. I'm running a pythonscript that is heavy on my processor. My first idea was to setup a cron-job that was running in the background and then in python cancel the job if the time is between 06:00 and 07:00 in the morning. (The job should ideally only be canceled at certain stages.)

```
0 1 * * *  cd ~/web/im2txt/im2txt && ./train.sh >/Users/kristoffer/Desktop/train.py 2>/Users/kristoffer/Desktop/train.log
```

But then I got thinking, is there someway, either in python or via shell to run a script if the computer is not being used? Is in idle or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xscreensaver` can run any program that is specified in its configuration file, i.e.:

```
          programs:  \
                  qix -root                          \n\
                  ico -r -faces -sleep 1 -obj ico    \n\
                  xdaliclock -builtin2 -root         \n\
                  xv -root -rmode 5 image.gif -quit  \n
```

then, you can add your own and let xscreensaver do the rest determining when your computer is idle.

Comment: Nice idea! (Pun intended:))

Comment: The question is: why running the program at a low priority all the time when there's no other process competing because you are not using it

Comment: Is this native in osx?

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to make your program run with lower priority compared to other processes is using the [`nice`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nice.1.html) command:

```
nice -n 20 ./train.sh
```

The command will run all the time, but the scheduler will give it the lowest possible priority, effectively giving it CPU time only when there is nothing else to do.

Note, however, that `nice` will only make the process nice (hence the name) to other princesses. If no other processes are competing for CPU time, a CPU-hungry process will utilize 100% of available cores (and heat up the machine), even when niced to the lowest priority.

Comment: nice! however, it still seems to push my cpu pretty hard, draining batttery and turning my laptop into a stove, so not really applicable for this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, `nice ` will only make the process nice (hence the name) to other princesses. If no other processes are competing for CPU time, even a lowest-priority niced CPU-hungry process will cheerfully utilize 100% of available cores, thus heating up the machine.